# SixLabors/ImageSharp breaks down some jpegs

Tags: c#, image-processing, imagesharp

My code:

```
using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load("1.jpg"))
{
      image.Mutate(ctx => ctx.Resize(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2));
      image.Save("2.jpg");
}
```

Input image: 
[1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta5cB.jpg)

Result: [2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja1H1.jpg)

Other images works good, but some of them is not. What wrong with it? And What I shoul do to process this image?

Comment: Not familiar with imagesharp, but, you're loading the jpeg as `Rgba32`. As far as I know, jpegs are rgb24, not rgba... maybe that's a possible cause?

Comment: Usually a good idea to add version numbers etc so someone can help you. 

@Nyerguds the pixel format is generic and represents how you want the decoded uncompressed image to be arranged in memory.

Comment: I used **1.0.0-beta0004**, and tried **1.0.0-beta0005**. This is latest versions available from nuget pugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing using the latest development build [1.0.0-dev002271](https://www.myget.org/feed/sixlabors/package/nuget/SixLabors.ImageSharp/1.0.0-dev002271) produces the correct output.

```bash
PM> Install-Package SixLabors.ImageSharp -Version 1.0.0-dev002271 -Source https://www.myget.org/F/sixlabors/api/v3/index.json
```

[image: Koala]

Comment: Thanks, it's helped